# Hover эффект появления точки

Tags: css, hover

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать появление зеленой точки на `:hover`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вариант 1

```css
a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 25px;
  position: relative;
  background: #E6E988;
}

a:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 50%;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  margin-left: -5px;
  background: green;
  border-radius: 50%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .3s ease;
}

a:hover:after {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Link</a>
```

Вариант 2

```css
a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 25px;
  position: relative;
  background: #E6E988;
}

a:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 50%;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  margin-left: -5px;
  background: green;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: scale(0);
  transition: transform .3s ease;
}

a:hover:after {
  transform: scale(1);
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Link</a>
```

Comment: эффекты мне понравились ставлю плюсик

Comment: Спасибо, сработало :)

Comment: @soledar10 поздравляю с  новым достижением 20.000!